# Writing array to a single cell with carriage returns

Tags: javascript, arrays, text, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write (a range) array data to a single cell with the elements separated by a carriage return when the value is set in the target cell.  The range of cells (the array data) holds data that is full of ", *, =, X and such so it needs to be converted to text before writing it to the target cell.

I can get the array elements written to a single cell, but it's in one continuous string lacking carriage returns.

```
function scTest() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var content2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");
    var indicator2 = content2.getRange(1, 1, 7, 5).getValues();
    var text = indicator2.toString()
    var targetCell = content2.getRange(10, 1).setValue(text);
}
```

I've been trying all kinds of combinations trying to separate the elements with a "\n" which is what I think it requires before you set the value of the target.
Thanks in advance for any help you can lend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a global replace:

```
function scTest() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var content2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");
    var indicator2 = content2.getRange(1, 1, 7, 5).getValues();
    var text = indicator2.toString();

    text = text.replace(/,/g,"\n");//Global replace of all commas with \n

    var targetCell = content2.getRange(10, 1).setValue(text);


}
```

Comment: You Rock!  Thank you so much.  :)  I'm a noob as you can tell.  I'll add this to my wheelhouse.  Thanks again.